# Fix Windows Restart after Dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Dual booted over Windows 10 1803 (Which was preinstalled). But while actually booting into Windows I did not notice any bug. However after trying to reboot in-Windows, something odd occurred. It did never reboot, while just looping into the reboot screen.

Comment: What reboot screen?

Comment: It just shows restarting......., but never actually restarts. Just loops into it.